# Have Pandoc generate PDF with bookmarks open similar to how LaTeX can

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to have `pandoc` generate a PDF where the bookmarks are opened like they can be in LaTeX using `\usepackage[open=true]{bookmark}`. I am currently using this command

```
pandoc \
  --from=markdown \
  --to=latex \
  --output=Setting_Branch_Policies_and_Security.pdf \
  --standalone \
  --variable papersize=a4paper \
  title.yml \
  Setting_Branch_Policies_and_Security.md
```

The Markdown document in question has some nested sections and subsections in it. The current PDF that gets generated has all the bookmarks there, but they're not open by default when the document is opened in a PDF reader like Okular or SumatraPDF.

How does one get the bookmarks to be expanded when a PDF that is generated by Pandoc when opened in PDF reader?

Comment: The default latex template loads `bookmark` without options. You can get the template with `pandoc -D latex` and change the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the default latex template:

```
pandoc -D latex > mytemplate.latex
```

Change the line containing `\usepackage{bookmark}` to `\usepackage[open=true]{bookmark}` and call pandoc with the template option:

```
pandoc \
  --from=markdown \
  --to=latex \
  --template=mytemplate.latex \
  --output=Setting_Branch_Policies_and_Security.pdf \
  --standalone \
  --variable papersize=a4paper \
  title.yml \
  Setting_Branch_Policies_and_Security.md
```